# Can mount nfs dir, but unable to mount subdir?

Tags: nfs

Have an odd issue where am able to mount a dir via NFS, but not able to mount any of that same dir's subdirs. Eg. On host server (CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)), have dirs

```bsh
[root@hwdatalake datalake]# pwd
/datalake

[root@hwdatalake datalake]# ls -lha .
total 8.0K
drwxrwx---. 14 root    etlusers     4.0K Dec 24 10:03 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root    root          240 Dec 12 10:24 ..
dr-xr-x---.  2 root    root           29 Dec 16 11:08 CUPSS_HI
dr-xr-x---.  2 root    root           29 Dec 16 11:16 CUPSS_NAT
dr-xr-x---.  2 root    root           26 Dec 16 11:17 NAT_BRFSS
```

and have `/etc/exports` as

```bsh
/datalake       airflowetl(rw,fsid=0,root_squash,sync)
/datalake/HI_BRFSS      airflowetl(ro,root_squash,sync)
```

On the client named airflowetl server (CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)), am able to successfully mount the toplevel dir from the nfs server...

```bsh
[root@airflowetl airflow]# mount -v hwdatalake.co.local:/datalake /dlnfs
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Dec 30 13:04:59 2019
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=172.18.4.97,clientaddr=172.18.4.69'=
```

but also see

```bsh
[root@airflowetl airflow]# umount /dlnfs
[root@airflowetl airflow]# showmount -e hwdatalake
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 113 (No route to host)
```

and when trying to mount the subdir instead, we see

```bsh
[root@airflowetl airflow]# mount -v hwdatalake.co.local:/datalake/HI_BRFSS /dlnfs
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Dec 30 13:12:55 2019
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=172.18.4.97,clientaddr=172.18.4.69'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=172.18.4.97,clientaddr=172.18.4.69'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=172.18.4.97'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=172.18.4.97,clientaddr=172.18.4.69'
```

Yet the previous dir was able to be mounted and already have firewall setting ostensibly configured...

```bsh
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=ssh
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=nfs
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Not really sure what to make of this. Anyone with more experience have any further debugging tips or know what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, based on

```bsh
showmount -e hwdatalake
RPC: Remote system errorRPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Timed out.
```

did...

```bsh
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=mountd
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=rpc-bind
firewall-cmd --reload
```

to check that the rpc service was not getting caught in the firewall, which fixed both the problem with `showmount` and being able to mount the lower level dirs.

Used this [article](https://www.howtoforge.com/nfs-server-and-client-on-centos-7) (was previously using similar article [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/setting-up-an-nfs-server-and-client-on-centos-7) that omitted these steps)